# Add object to data table of the page before saving. Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm leaving the JSF environment and I have some doubts when using Spring mvc with Thymeleaf. As in the example below, I have the account object related to a tariff list, what I am trying to accomplish is to add the tariffs of the account being registered in the tariff list that is in my object account, so, when saving the object of the account, fees are recorded through the waterfall. What is the best way to implement this simple funcinality with spring and thymeleaf.

**Account Class**

```
public class Account {

    private Integer accountNumber;
    private BigDecimal balance;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Rate.class, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="RateCode", foreignKey= @ForeignKey(name = "fk_account_rate"))
    private List<Rate> rates;

    // get and sets
}
```

**Rate**

```
public class Rate {

    private Long rateCode;
    private String rateName;
    private BigDecimal value;


    // get and sets

}
```

**Controller Account**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView new(Account account) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("page/account/cadAccount");
        model.addObject("rate", new Rate());
        model.addObject(account);

        return model;
    }
}
```

**Page Account**

```
<form th:object="${account}" method="POST" th:action="@{/account/save}">
    <gff:message/>

    <div class="box-body">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{accountCode}"/>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#tab_conta" data-toggle="tab">Account</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tab_tarifas" data-toggle="tab">Rates</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_conta">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group" gff:classforerror="name">

                                <label>Account name</label> 

                                <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control input-sm">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4" gff:classforerror="balance">

                            <label>Balance</label>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{balance}" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ " class="form-control currency input-sm">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_tarifas">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Rate Name</label> 

                                <input id="nomeTarifa" type="text" th:field="${rate.name}" class="form-control input-sm">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                            <label>Value</label>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>
                                <input id="valorTarifaID" type="text" th:field="${rate.value}" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ " class="form-control currency input-sm">
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">

                            <a class="btn btn-info pull-left" th:href="@{/account/add}">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                Add
                            </a>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td data-title="Name"></td>
                                    <td data-title="Value"></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>

                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-footer">
        <button id="salveButtonID" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ajax">Salve</button>

        <a class="btn btn-default ajax" th:href="@{/}">Cancel</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Read about [using dynamic fields](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields).

Comment: Thank you @JakubCh.